# Is there an Applicative analogue for type-aligned sequences?

Tags: haskell, types, gadt

Type-aligned sequences are sequences of indexed types whose indices must match up end to end. The simplest example is

```
data TList c x z where
  TNil :: TList c x x
  TCons :: c x y -> TList c y z -> TList c x z
```

There's no sensible way in general** to "zip" two `TList`s together, but I'm guessing there might be some way to express a Cartesian-product-like operation like `<*>` for `[]`. The general idea would be to link up the index at the end of each "row" to the one at the beginning of the next. But I'm having trouble working out how to do this. It would be especially cool if I could figure out how to write an implementation for type-aligned finger trees similar to the ultra-lazy one in `Data.Sequence`.

** This is possible with indices of kind `()` and an appropriate postulate, but for most kinds this must take a function completely polymorphic in all four indices and return something existential. Not so useful.

Comment: What about the existing finger tree in `type-aligned`? So, is that different in some important way to `Data.Sequence`?

Comment: @AndrásKovács, I don't think it offers anything like `Applicative`. And it is different. `Data.Sequence` has size annotations to support random indexing and splitting. The one in `type-aligned` does not, perhaps because these operations aren't known to be useful for reflection without remorse. It's a bit surprising that they used Hinze-Paterson shaped trees rather than Okasaki-shaped ones, under the circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

What we can certainly do is

```
tlConcat :: TList (TList c) x z -> TList c x z
tlConcat TNil = id
tlConcat (TCons f l) = f >>> tlConcat l
```

(I'm assuming the obvious `Category` instance to “mappend” those arrow-chains.)

If we combine that with a `map` analogue

```
tlMap :: (∀ a b . c a b -> d a b) -> TList c x y -> TList d x y
tlMap _ TNil = TNil
tlMap t (TCons f l) = TCons (t f) tlMap t l
```

we basically have a monad.

As for `<*>` style applicative, we'll somehow need to wrap that polymorphism:

```
data CaFun c d a b where
  CaFun :: (∀ α β . c α β -> d α β) -> CaFun c d x x
```

Then,

```
tlAp :: TList (CaFun c d) x y -> TList c x x -> TList d x x
tlAp _ TNil = TNil
tlAp TNil _ = TNil
tlAp (TCons (CaFun f) l) q = tlMap f q >>> tlAp l q
```

Of course this is a bit boring: `CaFun` basically subverts the entire point of type-alignment, by forcing type equality. There might be a better way yet.

Here's something zip-alike instead:

```
tlLiftA2 :: (∀ α β γ δ . c α β -> d γ δ -> e (α,γ) (β,δ))
          -> TList c φ ψ -> TList d χ ω -> TList e (φ,χ) (ψ,ω)
tlLiftA2 _ TNil TNil = TNil
tlLiftA2 q (TCons f l) (TCons g m) = TCons (q f g) (tlLiftA2 q l m)
```

You notice that this only works with equal-length lists, but we can repair this quite well:

```
tlLiftA2 :: (Category c, Category d) =>
        (∀ α β γ δ . c α β -> d γ δ -> e (α,γ) (β,δ))
          -> TList c φ ψ -> TList d χ ω -> TList e (φ,χ) (ψ,ω)
tlLiftA2 q TNil (TCons g m) = TCons (q id g) $ tlLiftA2 q TNil m
tlLiftA2 q (TCons f l) TNil = TCons (q f id) $ tlLiftA2 q l TNil
```

Comment: Your `liftA2` attempts to be `zipWith`, so I will be shocked if it actually compiles. There's nothing to ensure the indices take the same path from origin to destination in each list.

Comment: You're right, I think, that it should be `liftA2`, but I want Cartesian product-style, which I think might be possible, rather than `zipWith`-style, which I don't think is usefully so.

Comment: Hm... seems indeed that `liftA2` doesn't go.

Comment: I'm thinking about something like `tliftA2 :: (forall x y z w :: c x y -> d z w -> e '(x, z) '(y, w)) -> TList c p q -> TList d r s -> TList e '(p, r) '(q, s)`, I think. But I'm not sure if that quite works.

Comment: ...and I think it could be possible to shape this into something cartesian-product-ish too.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! I was thinking if that signature for the Cartesian product one (which I'd still really like to see). I didn't realize it could work for equal-length zipping as well!

Comment: By the way, it's possible, with an appropriate (non-categorical) `c` to add awkward length indexing to these, allowing you to express a total zip of the form you discovered.